# Confirmation email address error code 16

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

My [swtor](http://www.swtor.com/) (Star Wars: Old Republic - Free to Play account) char hit level 16 yesterday. When i try to enter the game with my character i get the `Error code 16` (you must validate email address). I already tried changing it, but getting the same error.

I already validated my email address days ago when i created the account, even validate it with the new email address. Still same error

The error reported in swtor states the following:

> To continue playing this character, you must validate an email
> address for your account. You may validate your email account by
> visiting
>
> account.swtor.com/user/info
>
> Error code: 16

Comment: Validate email address?  That means the game sent you an email with a link.  Follow that link.

Comment: i already validated my email address days ago, even validate it with the new email address. Still same error.

Comment: Ahh.  That's information you should add to your question.

Comment: You should probably contact the game's support staff for this one.

Comment: You should post your fix as an answer and mark it as the answer. ;)

Comment: @leety done, tomorrow i will be able to mark it as answered.

Comment: Hey, @EH_warch, I removed the game name from the title; it's sorta redundant due to the way SEO works on the SE network.  It adds the first two tags into the title already, so having it in the title puts it there twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To anyone having the same issue, here is what i've done:

- Changed email address(did not work)
- Go to [Origin Website](http://store.origin.com/), verified email and changed password(did not work)
- [Called support - Billing](http://www.swtor.com/support/form)(sill working on this, recommended)

**Update**

After a couple of hours on the phone with customer service - billing, i got it working. What they did was help me register an account that did not had any EA accounts associated, then they moved my character from the former account to the new one and now its working.

If you are experience this problem is most likely because in some moment on time you linked that email address with a EA account (if you either remember or not), and what you need to do (in case you dont want to talk to support center) is to change the SWTOR email address until you find an email which is not related at all with EA (For example a new email address). After that you can go back playing the game.

Remember that even [Origin](http://store.origin.com/) is related to EA

**Update 2**

I totally forgot that another thing that i did was start using the email address instead of the nickname at the login screen, hope that gladly help someone.

**Note**: The verification email isn't sent for several minutes after the change is made on the site - I forgot about this, and is important(Eroen).

Comment: Running into the same issue, I attempted logging in with email, "changing" to same address and contacting support. None worked, I couldn't make the ticket submission form work in *any available* browser. Changing to a (EA untainted) address and verifying it worked around the issue. The verification email isn't sent for several minutes after the change is made on the site, however. TIP: Gmail supports "+whatever" suffixes to addresses.